# How do you test out Hasura authorization?

Tags: graphql, authorization, hasura, hasura-jwt

If I disable `x-hasura-admin-secret` in the Dashboard, and add `Authorization: Bearer a_jwt_encoded_with_a_HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET_and_the_hasura_custom_claims`

Then I keep getting these toast notifications:

```
Schema introspection query failed
x-hasura-admin-secret/x-hasura-access-key required, but not found
```

What am I missing? How can I test my permissions and such from within the Hasura GraphiQL explorer?

---

My `HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET` might be in the wrong place. I set it in Heroku (per how you used to have to do it).

---

I've updated the `HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET` to be defined in the Hasura project console's env vars, and have updated it to

```
{
    "key": "01234567890123456789012345678912",
    "type": "HS256"
}
```

But when I generate a JWT from that config and try it, it throws the same toast notifications...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience the easiest way to test permissions is to leave the admin secret in place and then just set the relevant headers.

Generally you just add additional headers for `x-hasura-role` and `x-hasura-user-id` and any other session variables that are relevant for your app.

In the screenshot below you can see that I've explicitly set these values. Any query that  you run will be evaluated based on the permissions associated with the role (in my case its `organization-admin`)

This is especially useful if you want to be able to use the `Analyze` functionality to do query profiles that take permissions into account.

[image: hasura console]